# What is the name of this type of network flow problem?

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, integer-programming, network-flow, mixed-integer-programming

I encountered a specific type of network flow problem, and I want to know if this type of problem has already been studied before. However, I have been unable to find relevant literature because I don't know what to call it.

The problem considers a layered directed acyclic graph $G=(V,A)$ with a root node $r$ and a sink node $t$. The arc set related to each layer has a non-empty subset of arcs with label 1. To give an example of such a graph, consider the following [example graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3YBI.png). In this example, each row of nodes constitutes a layer, all arcs are directed away from $r$ towards $t$, and the labeled arcs in each layer are drawn full while all unlabeled arcs are drawn dashed.

The problem I intend to solve is finding a minimum $r-t$ flow such that, in each layer, exactly one labeled arc has a nonzero flow, and this flow has a value of 1. On our example graph, we would have the following [minimum flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C19P7.png). Here, all arcs colored green have a flow of 1 going through them unless indicated otherwise with another number (2 or 3).

To solve this problem, I use the following integer programming formulation:

\begin{align}
    & \min \sum_{a \in \delta^+(r)} y(a) & \nonumber \\
    \text{s.t.} & \sum_{a = (u,v)|L(u) = j, \ell(a)=1} y(a) = 1 & \forall~j \in N \label{cons:nfm_onearcs}\\
    & \sum_{a \in \delta^- (u)} y(a) - \sum_{a \in \delta^+ (u)} y(a) = 0 & \forall~ u \in V \setminus \{r, t\} \label{cons:nfm_flowconservation}\\
    & y(a) \in \{0,1,...,n\} &\forall~a \in A \label{cons:nfm_integrality}
\end{align}
where:

- y(a) is an integer variable modelling the flow through arc $a$
- $\delta^+(v)$ is the set of outgoing arcs of a node $v$. Likewise, $\delta^-(v)$ is the set of incoming arcs.
- $L(v)$ is the layer of a node $v$, and $N$ denotes the set of layers.
- $\ell(a)$ denotes the label of an arc $a$ (either 0 or 1)

The second set of constraints are flow-balance constraints, the first set of constraints enforces that, in each layer, only one labeled arc has a flow of 1 (along with the integrality constraints). The formulation minimizes the overall flow through the network by minimizing the flow through the outgoing arcs of the root node.

I would like to know if this problem or similar problems have already been studied. I would call this a minimum flow problem on a layered graph with set covering constraints (as the first set of constraints can also be rewritten to a set covering constraint, i.e. $\geq 1$ constraints). However, I have not been able to find literature on this problem using this terminology or similar phrasing. Therefore, I want to know: what search terms could I use to find more about this problem?

Thanks in advance for your help! If anything is unclear, please indicate it so I can try to refine my post :)

Comment: What is the motivation for the rule about labeled arcs?

Comment: This problem is a subproblem of a graph coloring algorithm, and the graph in the example is a binary decision diagram (DD). Consider a graph G'=(V',E') that we intend to color. We build a DD where each layer relates to a node in V'. Consider an r-t path on this DD. All one-arcs on this r-t path correspond to a subset of the nodes of V'. For example, the left-most path in the example, (0,0,1,1,0,0,1) in terms of arc-labels, corresponds to the set of nodes {v3, v4, v7} on the graph that was used to generate this DD.

Comment: We wish to build our DD such that all possible r-t paths encode all independent sets of G'. Then, consider a minimum flow on this DD such that, in each layer, only one one-arc is chosen. If you decompose this flow into paths, and each path encodes an independent set, then the collection of these paths encode a minimum coloring of G'. For more information, see the publication "Graph coloring with decision diagrams" by van Hoeve (2021): https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10107-021-01662-x.